# Django email address not showing in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to create a simple email and name collector , everything looks fine but I can only see the name option in the admin site the email option is not there

[admin page model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nqu6.jpg)

Here is my code

```
Forms.py
from django import forms
from sonus import models
from django import forms  

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label="Your Name",max_length=20) 
    your_email = forms.EmailField(label="Email",max_length=100)
```

Here Goes my Views.py

```
def get_name(request):
    person = Person()

    if request.method=="POST":
       form = NameForm(request.POST)

       if form.is_valid(): 
            person.name = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
            person.email = form.cleaned_data['your_email']
            person.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index')) 

    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request,'form.html',{ 'form': form })
```

My Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.decorators import display
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import Details, Person,list
from sonus import models

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Person)
```

Here is the model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = TextField(max_length=20)
    email = EmailField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('person',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: Don't create the person on the first line of the view. Only create it if the form if valid. You should also use a model form. See [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm)

Answer (score 1):

In your **admin.py** change your code to that :

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email',)
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks you Answer is helpful This is what i'm seeing now adding this code to my Admin                          Non-fiction <django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0x0000024E547E9C70>
 oooo <django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0x0000024E547E9C70>
 dfgd <django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0x0000024E547E9C70>
 omg <django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0x0000024E547E9C70>